# Contour Plot with logarithmic scale

Tags: plotting, filling

I am trying to plot an equation using contour plot with x-axis in logarithmic scale.

```
K1 = 0.0001104;

K2 = -1.7259*10^(-5);

K3 = -2.3125*10^(-6);

K4 = -1.7322*10^(-7);

Lambda0 = 1.550;

m1 = 4*K4*V^3 + 3*K3*V^2 + 2*K2*V + K1;

m3 = 4*K4*V + K3;

k0 = ((2*3.14)/Lambda0*L1);

v0 = 1;

CIMD3 = (3/8*v0^3)*(1/6*(k0*m1)^3 - k0*m3);

IMD3dBm = 10*Log10[CIMD3/0.001];

pl = Normal@
  ContourPlot[IMD3dBm, {L1, 0, 1000}, {V, 0, 6}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Cases[pl, Line[a_, b___] :> a, Infinity], 
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.9]
```

[image]

It is producing contour plot in logarithmic scale without filling the contours. How to fill it?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}` to `ContourPlot` gives

[image]